# git-lfs unable to install in apple silicon macOS monterey

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

i install git-lfs using homebrew

then i follow

```
# Update global git config
$ git lfs install

# Update system git config
$ git lfs install --system
```

I get the following error

```
WARNING: current user is not root/admin, system install is likely to fail.
WARNING: error running /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git 'config' '--includes' '--system' '--replace-all' 'filter.lfs.clean' 'git-lfs clean -- %f': 'error: could not lock config file /etc/gitconfig: Permission denied' 'exit status 255'
Run `git lfs install --force` to reset git config.
```

for the `install -- system` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git lfs install
sudo git lfs install --system
```

to get past the permissions issue

Comment: which version does this work for? I get the response - git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.